# Having issue with importing photos from camera to computer

Tags: canon

I want to import photos in bulk directly from my camera to a Windows 7 computer.

When I did some research, I found there might be an issue with the file transfer mode (MTS vs UMS)

In Win7, the default mode is MTS. I tried, but was not able to find any way to convert it to UMS.

When I try to import photos directly from the camera in bulk, it shows an error like
'Cannot open multiple items from this location. Try selecting a single item instead.'

Comment: What camera is this? Whar software are you using?

Comment: What cable are you using? OR wireless? Or through a card reader?

Comment: I am not using any software.
Camere is Canon SX 110.
I just plugin data cabel to computer >> It will show me drive in my computer >> At the location where it needs to import i go to that location and it will open (Open window from where we can select photos) >> I am going to camera drive >> select multiple photos and it will shows error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to transfer photos in bulk (and in a fairly organized way) is to install the zoombrowser utility and/or camera window utility. These can be found here: http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/digital_cameras/other_powershot/powershot_sx110_is_black#DriversAndSoftware

Using this you can specify a default drive/directory where all the photos are transferred.
You can also specify the basic organization of photos (like store photos by month, date etc)
If you do not want to connect the camera and use the SD card alone using a card reader, then the software provides a SD card utility.

Comment: But how it is working fine without anything in XP.
why only creating issue in windows 7 ??